# Scrapy/Python: Processing values in a yield

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to write a crawler using Scrapy/Python, that reads some values from a page.

I then want this crawler to store the highest and lowest values in seperate fields.

So far, I am able to read the values from the page (please see my code below), but I am not sure how to calculate the lowest and highest value and store in separate fields ?

For example, say the crawler reads the page and returns these values

- burvale-score = 75.25
- richmond-score = 85.04
- somano-score = '' (value missing)
- tucson-score = 90.67
- cloud-score = 50.00

So I want to populate ....

- 'highestscore': 90.67
- 'lowestscore': 50.00

How do I do that ? Do I need to use an array ? Put all values in array and then pick the highest/lowest ?

**Also, please note that there are 2 `yield` in my code .... The bottom `yield` is providing URLs to crawl, and the first `yield` actually crawl/collects the values from each URL that is provided by the bottom `yield`**

Any help is very appreciated. Please provide code examples if you can.

**Here is my code so far** .... I am storing -1, in case of missing values.

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "courses"
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/all-courses-listing']
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    def parse(self, response):
     hxs = Selector(response)
    #for courses in response.xpath(response.body):
     for courses in response.xpath("//meta"):
     yield {
                'pagetype': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetype"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pagefeatured': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagefeatured"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pagedate': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagedate"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pagebanner': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagebanner"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pagetitle': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetitle"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pageurl': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageurl"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pagedescription': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagedescription"]/@content').extract_first(),
                'pageid': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageid"]/@content').extract_first(),

                'courseatarburvale': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-burvale"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                'courseatarrichmond': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-richmond"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                'courseatarsomano': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-somano"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                'courseatartucson': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-tucson"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                'courseatarcloud': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-cloud"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                'highestscore'; ??????
                'lowestscore'; ??????
               }
     for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract():
      yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably break down this part of code:

```
yield {
    'pagetype': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetype"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagefeatured': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagefeatured"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagedate': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagedate"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagebanner': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagebanner"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagetitle': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetitle"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pageurl': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageurl"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagedescription': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagedescription"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pageid': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageid"]/@content').extract_first(),

    'courseatarburvale': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-burvale"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatarrichmond': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-richmond"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatarsomano': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-somano"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatartucson': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-tucson"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatarcloud': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-cloud"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'highestscore'; ??????
    'lowestscore'; ??????
}
```

into this:

```
item = {
    'pagetype': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetype"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagefeatured': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagefeatured"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagedate': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagedate"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagebanner': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagebanner"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagetitle': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetitle"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pageurl': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageurl"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pagedescription': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagedescription"]/@content').extract_first(),
    'pageid': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageid"]/@content').extract_first(),
}

scores = {
    'courseatarburvale': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-burvale"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatarrichmond': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-richmond"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatarsomano': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-somano"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatartucson': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-tucson"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
    'courseatarcloud': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="courseatar-cloud"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
}

values = sorted(x for x in scores.values() if x > 0)
scores.update({
    'highestscore': values[-1],
    'lowestscore': values[0],
})

item.update(scores)
yield item
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomáš Linhart I am working on a similar approach .... I will report back shortly ... Cheers

Comment: Hi @Tomáš Linhart When I tried you suggestion, I got this error .... _IndexError: list index out of range_ Any ideas ? Its complaining on this line  `'highestatar': values[-1],`

Comment: @Slyper Probably `values` list is empty, which can occur if no scores are extracted from the page (i.e. `scores` contains only -1's). So change the highest score assignment code to `'highestscore': values[-1] if values else None` and likewise for lowest score.

Comment: Thanks @Tomáš Linhart Everything is working now. Great answer. Cheers....